# boost datetime return value after adding or substracting days

Tags: c++, boost

I would like to return either a boost datetime object or simply a string one after I do something like this

```
RETURN_OBJECT GetDateTime(int n)
{
  return new DateTime(10,10,10).AddDays(n);
}
```

The return value is DateTime(10,10+n,10);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The year `10` is not a valid date for the boost gregorian date type (valid range 1400..10000).

Here's an adjusted sample, basically from the documentation

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98cc6ce457a117f5)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_date.hpp>

boost::gregorian::date GetDateTime(int n)
{
  return boost::gregorian::date (2010,1,1) + boost::gregorian::days(n);
}

#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_io.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << GetDateTime(42);
}
```

Prints

```
2010-Feb-12
```